# error in mysql prepared statement timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using mysql to develop basic ddl statements but I created table with datatype of timestamp and getting an error as invalid statement for timestamp. And my code is :

```
ps.setTimestamp(4, m_datetime);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is no `SQL` as I know it... What language/interface are we working with?

Comment: It is a normal JDBC connection with PrepareStatement and using Timestamp as datatype and in insert command I used above line but I am getting error like "Not Suitable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps.setTimestamp(4, m_datetime);
```

make sure that `m_datetime` has the proper `timestamp` format and its data type is `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Instead of java.sql.Timestamp I used java.security.Timestamp.     Thank you john